# Asus HD 7750 - The VGA card is not supported by UEFI driver.

Tags: windows, windows-8, uefi, secure-boot, cms

I installed windows 8 on my pc with uefi enabled. 
After installing it when i am turning off the CMS and enabling secure boot, i am getting this message.
"The VGA card is not supported by UEFI driver."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU must support the new Video Protocol from which is called Graphics Output Protocol (GOP). Disable the **fastBoot** option in the UEFI firmware to fix it. Now the old VGA loading is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
but i want the fast boot feature on my system and you are telling to disable it. Please help me to enable this. and tell me whether I've to upgrade the bios of my card? If so, where can i find it?

Comment: Yeah upgrading the video BIOS should do it... there exists one for your card enabling GOP.

Comment: try the VGA BIOS Update from here: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/vga/ASUS_VGA_UEFI_VBIOS_Update.zip http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=9&s=10&m=HD7750-1GD5&os=&hashedid=YeoAjoCWA2Nxup5t